# 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk' error while using UpdateView in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to use the UpdateView for editing a product (model), but it seems it doesn't identify my pk (id) parameter in the url.

here's my setup

in my views.py

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
class ProductDetail(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name="inventory/product-detail.html"
    success_url = "new-product/success"
    fields = "__all__"

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        id = int(kwargs.pk)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
        return product
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('<pk>/update/', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]
```

here's the traceback log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 203, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 31, in get_object
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
  File "D:\pythonDjango\BHM Inventory System\inventory\views.py", line 45, in get_queryset
    id = int(kwargs.pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /products/2001/update/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

It seems on python views generic\edit.py it was able to read the 'pk' in the kwargs but not in my views that i have extended the UpdateView. as you can see on the ff. screenshot with the variables
[django traceback variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kgJV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write your custom `get_queryset` method as `UpdateView` handle it for you automatically. If you would use another url kwarg, you could define it with `pk_url_kwarg`, but this is not the case in your example. Read more in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg).

I also recommend always setting a converter type in your URL pattern like `...path('<int:pk>/update/'...`

Btw. `get_queryset` does not have kwargs available to get `GET` parameters. If you really need to access them, you can acces them in `self.request.GET`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am enlighten with your answer.